How can I retrieve custom parameters from External Credentials with Apex?
I'm looking to retrieve some External Credential information in an Apex class, and so far I've been successful in retrieving everything except for the parameters associated with the credential's principal.
I'm using the getExternalCredential(String developerName) method documented here.
I thought because 'parameters' is listed as a property in this documentation, I would be able to access it in the response, but maybe I'm misinterpreting the documentation.
The parameters property is being returned, but with an empty list. I tried referencing the parameters directly through the External Credential as well as through the list of Principals returned, but there are no parameters being returned for either one.
What am I missing? Code snippet below.
public class GetCredentials {

// Method to get the External Credential
public static void getExternalCredential(String credName){

    // Get the external credential with the developer name
    ConnectApi.ExternalCredential cred = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getExternalCredential(credName);
    
    // This returns the master label of the credential
    system.debug('cred masterLabel: ' + cred.masterLabel);
    
    // This returns the list of principals
    system.debug('principals: ' + cred.principals);
    
    // This returns ()
    system.debug('parameters: ' + cred.parameters);
    
    
    // Loop the list of principals
    for(ConnectApi.ExternalCredentialPrincipal princ : cred.principals){
        
        // This returns ()
        system.debug('parameters: ' + princ.parameters);
    }
} }


is your class at V57 or higher? does the running user  have the View Setup and Configuration permission?

Similar to how Named Credentials work, these parameters are only available to the platform at runtime, you can't retrieve them.

@identigral - that makes sense as otherwise it opens a security hole; this should be the answer

@cropredy yes, View Setup and Configuration is applied for this user.

@identigral - thanks for the input. Turns out I don't actually need to retrieve them, I just need to update them, which I found is easily doable using the ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.updateCredential method!
